# How to exit a powershell script with exitcode after using Write-Error?

Tags: powershell, exit-code

I noticed that if I use `Write-Error` and after that `exit 123` the `$lastexitcode` variable is not changed, instead it still contains the exit code from the previous command.

Given I have these files:

`test-out.ps1`:

```
Write-Output "hello"
exit 3
```

`test-err.ps1`

```
Write-Error "hello"
exit 123
```

Then I call in a powershell:

```
.\test-out.ps1
// displays: hello
$lastexitcode
// displays: 3

.\test-err.ps1
// displays: Write-Error: hello
$lastexitcode
// also/still displays: 3
```

I expected `$lastexitcode` after `.\test-err.ps1` to be `123`.

My workaround is to use `[Console]::Error.WriteLine("hello")`, but it seems like Write-Error should be the preferred way of doing this.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error?view=powershell-7.2) says

> To write a non-terminating error, enter an error message string, an ErrorRecord object, or an Exception object. Use the other parameters of Write-Error to populate the error record.

It doesn't mention that it will prevent setting a custom exit code. And worse, using this doesn't set an exit code at all. If it was 0 before, then after using `Write-Error` and then `exit 1` won't even work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Dou you have a line `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` in your script? In this case `Write-Error` produces a script-terminating error, so the `exit 123` line won't be executed. Try `Write-Error "hello" -EA Continue` to ensure it doesn't terminate the script.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I indeed had `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` from a previous test or script still set. 

Comment: Albeit a proof was missing, the indices were obvious for investigator @mklement0 and his assistant zett42. After the confession of the main suspect, the case could finally be closed. ️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your symptom implies:

- that your `exit 123` statement was *never executed*
- which in turn means that [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error), which by default emits a *non*-terminating error, happened to emit a *script-terminating* error,
- which in turn implies that the [`$ErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) `= 'Stop'` was in effect.

Comment: I actually do have that in place (from a previous script call, I think, or maybe from testing things out). In a fresh Powershell my example does not work and the correct exitcode is set, Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @para.